# redefining the \textit command to use a custom italic font

Tags: luatex

I am currently using the robotto font, and since it is a custom font, is there anyway that I can use the `\textit` command to use the `Robotto-Italic.ttf` font? right now, here are some parts of my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto-Light.ttf}
\newfontfamily\robotolightit[Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto-LightItalic.ttf}

\begin{document}

\textit{Test item 1}

\end{document}
```

I when it right now, it just doesn't change the text. My first instinct was to do `\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{\robottolightitalic{#1}}` but that just made everything after the italicized text change to italics, even after the end brace.

Comment: `Ligatures=TeX` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `fontspec` do the job for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = *-Light,
  ItalicFont = *-LightItalic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{Roboto}

\begin{document}

Roboto Light

\textit{Roboto Light Italic}

\textbf{Roboto Bold}

\textbf{\textit{Roboto Bold Italic}}

\end{document}
```

[image]